# How to partition a SQL Server table with a modulus function

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008

I have an `Orders` table with some basic info like below:

```
+---------+---------+------------+-----------+
| OrderId | StoreId | StoreName  | ProductId |
+---------+---------+------------+-----------+
|       1 |    1001 | Store 1001 |       123 |
|       2 |    1002 | Store 1002 |       124 |
|       3 |    1003 | Store 1003 |       125 |
+---------+---------+------------+-----------+
```

I would like to partition this table by expression: `StoreId MOD 10`. I think that it can divide this table to 10 smaller tables.

How can I solve it using SQL Server?

Comment: edit the question with some more sample data & desired result would helpful.

Comment: Can you please put some example data and output?

Comment: Can you actually try something and if you have an issue, post some code with an actual question.

Comment: What do you mean with "divide into smaller tables"? You want just to get an ID to group them or you actually want to partition them physically? If the latter, you want to keep it as multiple partitions on the same table, or different tables?

Comment: @EzequielLópezPetrucci: Yes, I want to partition them physically, and I want to keep it as multiple partitions on the same table. I can do it with MySQL, but I am a newbie SQL Server. So I need to help.

Comment: The problem with partitioning by mod is that all of the partitions are going to be growing at the same time and *there's no easy way to introduce a new partition without having to tear everything down and rebuild it from scratch*. Hope you always have plenty of free storage space on your system.

Comment: @Damien_The_Unbeliever: Yes, I know that, but my problem now is how to do with this solution, maybe in the future I could mod by 100, I'm just a newbie about SQL Server, so I need to do this task.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `MOD` operator is `%` in SQL Server. Keep in mind that if you want non-zero numbers you should add 1 to the result.

```
SELECT
    StoreOrderGroup = (StoreId % 10) + 1,
    O.*
FROM
    Orders AS O
```

If you want to create 10 different tables with the same structure, you can use the resulting StoreOrderGroup to SELECT INTO and create them. This *won't replicate indexes or constraints*.

```
DECLARE @StoreOrderGroup INT
DECLARE @StoreOrderGroupTable VARCHAR(100)

DECLARE StoreOrderGroupCursor CURSOR FOR
    SELECT DISTINCT
        StoreOrderGroup = (StoreId % 10) + 1,
        StoreOrderGroupTable = QUOTENAME('OrdersStore' + CONVERT(VARCHAR(200), (StoreId % 10) + 1))
    FROM
        Orders
    ORDER BY
        StoreOrderGroup ASC

OPEN StoreOrderGroupCursor
FETCH NEXT FROM StoreOrderGroupCursor INTO @StoreOrderGroup, @StoreOrderGroupTable

WHILE @@FETCH_STATUS = 0
BEGIN

    DECLARE @DynamicSQLCreate VARCHAR(MAX) = '
        SELECT 
            * 
        INTO 
            ' + @StoreOrderGroupTable + ' 
        FROM 
            Orders
        WHERE
            (StoreId % 10) + 1 = ' + CONVERT(VARCHAR(200), @StoreOrderGroup)

    EXEC (@DynamicSQLCreate)

    FETCH NEXT FROM StoreOrderGroupCursor INTO @StoreOrderGroup, @StoreOrderGroupTable

END

CLOSE StoreOrderGroupCursor
DEALLOCATE StoreOrderGroupCursor
```

However, if you want to keep the same table but with different partitions, then you need to:

1. Create different filegroups to store each partition, with at least 1 file each and preferably on different hard drives. This is recommended but not mandatory.
2. Create a [PARTITION FUNCTION](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/statements/create-partition-function-transact-sql) which will recieve the store mod result as input parameter and return which partition it should be assigned to. The boundary limit values would be the integer numbers (careful with LEFT or RIGHT ranges).
3. Create a [PARTITION SCHEME](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/statements/create-partition-scheme-transact-sql) to link the partition function of point 2 with different filegroups from point 1. This will tell the engine in which filegroup should it store each partition.
4. Create a new table with your partition scheme and store all your orders.

A quick example:

```
ALTER DATABASE YourDatabase ADD FILEGROUP SuperFastFileGroup;  
GO  

ALTER DATABASE YourDatabase ADD FILEGROUP SuperSlowFileGroup;  
GO  

ALTER DATABASE YourDatabase   
ADD FILE   
(  
    NAME = FastFile,  
    FILENAME = 'C:\Program Files\Microsoft SQL Server\MSSQL13.MSSQLSERVER\MSSQL\DATA\FastFile.ndf',  
    SIZE = 5MB,  
    MAXSIZE = 100MB,  
    FILEGROWTH = 5MB  
)  
TO FILEGROUP SuperFastFileGroup;  
GO

ALTER DATABASE YourDatabase   
ADD FILE   
(  
    NAME = SlowFile,  
    FILENAME = 'D:\SQL Server\SlowFile.ndf',  
    SIZE = 5MB,  
    MAXSIZE = 100MB,  
    FILEGROWTH = 5MB  
)  
TO FILEGROUP SuperSlowFileGroup;  
GO  


CREATE PARTITION FUNCTION OrderStoreMod10 (int)
    AS RANGE LEFT FOR VALUES (1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9);  
GO  


CREATE PARTITION SCHEME OrderStoreScheme  
    AS PARTITION OrderStoreMod10  
    TO (
        SuperFastFileGroup, -- 1 or lower
        SuperFastFileGroup, -- 2
        SuperFastFileGroup, -- 3
        SuperFastFileGroup, -- 4
        SuperFastFileGroup, -- 5
        SuperFastFileGroup, -- 6
        SuperFastFileGroup, -- 7

        SuperSlowFileGroup, -- 8
        SuperSlowFileGroup, -- 9
        SuperSlowFileGroup); -- higher than 9
GO  


CREATE TABLE NewOrders (
    -- Your columns...
    StoreID INT,
    StoreOrderGroup AS StoreID % 10) -- ComputedColumn
    ON OrderStoreScheme (StoreOrderGroup);  
GO  

-- Insert your data into the new table
```

Please read [this post](https://www.sqlservercentral.com/Forums/1379099/Partitioning-on-a-computed-column-int-based) before using partition schemes on a table split by your StoreID, it might not be a good idea.

Comment: Thanks so much, you save my day, so I will try this solution, and inform to you if it works.

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
SELECT StoreId%10 [StoreId mod 10]
      ,StoreId 
      ,OrderId 
      ,StoreName  
      ,ProductId
FROM Orders
order by StoreId%10, OrderId
```